# Python Dataframe Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like some help with the following problem.

[image]

I would like to check if the bottom end for 20/01/2015 (blue circle) is either greater than the close of 21/01/2015 (red circle)
I can check this condition for the same day but am having difficulty to check it for the next day.

Ideally I would like to run a loop that will check this condition for the entire dataframe.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First [dont loop in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/2901002).

If need compare with next days rows use [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['test'] = df['Bottom End'].gt(df['Close'].shift(-1))
```